# How do I drop blocks instead of throwing them?

Tags: fez

I'm pretty sure Dot explained this early on, but I missed that explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hold ↓ while pressing the throw button

[image: You can also pick it up and throw it with X]
[image: And you can drop it down gently by pressing ↓ and X]